noImplicitAny activated - doesn't allow what exactly?
From the documentation and the internet, I understood that code like the following would cause a compilation error because TypeScript tries to infer the type of 's', sees it as 'any', but there is no declaration of the type of 's':
function fs(s){
    console.log(s.substr(3));
}

However, I am confused why the next code snippet would not cause an error:
let x;

If I hover over 'x', I see the type as "any", but I did not declare the type of 'x' anywhere. Additionally, I could do the following:
let x;
x = 5;
x = "22";
x = {a: 1, b: 2};

and still, no error would occur.
Could you please clarify what "noImplicitAny" means in this context?

This was intentionally added in TS 2.1 it seems. Read about improved any inference
Earlier
let x; // implicitly 'any'
let y = []; // implicitly 'any[]'
let z: any; // explicitly 'any'.

All the above would have caused errors. But after 2.1, TS is able to infer the type based on assignment.
let x;
// You can still assign anything you want to 'x'.
x = () => 42;

This improvement in control flow analysis was a part of this PR#11263.
Implicit errors should only be reported if TS is not able to find the type of a variable, without any type annotation.
In your example, it is quite straight forward what the type of x is.
Think of it like this, the above code is equivalent to:
let x = {a: 1, b: 2};

Won't it be annoying. Having the above as error? Now TS compiler is smart enough to not do that.
Coming to your code, while the type of x is any right now, as soon as you access it, it infers the correct type.


Another comment from one of the collaborators which helped me get it better was:
function foo(x?) {
    x.asdf; // error yes
}

let x;
x.asdf; // not allowed
if (Date.now()) {
    x = 'str';
    x.asdf; // not allowed
}
bar(x)
x.asdf; // not allowed

function bar(x: any) {
  x.asdf; // allowed, because I *did* write :any
}

TS is there to protect JS code from failing. It is not there to setup its own rules which would be perfectly valid and error free in JS right.
